# Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/api/auth/register

Tags: reactjs, node.js

Я работаю над проектом с Node.js, React.js и MongoDB.

Когда я отправляю запрос на сервер, я получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/api/auth/login

Клиентская часть работает на порту 3000, сервер - на порту 6000. Я пробовал много решений, которые есть в Интернете, но мне это не помогло.

Файл Server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const logger = require('./logger');
const cors = require("cors");

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express()
const port = 6000
const host = "0.0.0.0";

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/eduDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB", err);
  });

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);

logger.info('Info message');
logger.error('Error message');


app.listen(port, host)
```

Файл на стороне клиента package.json:

```
   {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:6000/",
  "private": true,  
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },  
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

setupProxy.js:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {app.use(createProxyMiddleware("/api/", {target:"http://localhost:6000",secure: false,changeOrigin: true}));}
```

Comment: Я работаю над проектом с Node.js, React.js и MongoDB. Когда я отправляю запрос на сервер, я получаю ошибку. Я пробовал много решений, которые есть в Интернете, но мне это не помогло.